# Creating folder by user entering name

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am trying to create a folder by having a user typing the name of the folder:

```
Scanner scanner;
String inputUser;

public void createDir(String input){
    System.out.print("Please enter name of Folder: ");
    this.inputUser = this.scanner.next().toUpperCase();

    File makeDir = new File("C:\\" + this.inputUser);

    try{
        if(!makeDir.exists()){
            makeDir.mkdir();
            System.out.println("You have created directory " + makeDir.getName());
        }else{
            System.out.println("Directory with name " + makeDir.getName() + " already exists.");
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error while creating directory name " + makeDir.getName());
    }
}
```

but every time when I run it I am getting the following error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>   Please enter name of Folder:    at filemanagerapp.FileManagerSystem.createDir(FileManagerSystem.java:68)
>       at filemanagerapp.FileManagerApp.main(FileManagerApp.java:42)

Java Result: 1

I have noticed that the line that is causing the problem is `this.inputUser` as when I remove it and try hard coding the name of folder to create, it creates normally with no problem, but I want user to enter name of folder if possible.

Can anyone tell me why this error is happening?

Comment: `scanner` is `null` or you left out the code that initializes it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `Scanner scanner` with `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)`

Comment: Thank you Atri, totally missed to enter full scanner class .... so simple but effective :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add Scanner:

```
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  inputUser = scanner.next().toUpperCase();
```